# Disappearing WordPress Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

The problem that it is reaching the custom menu items limit. Anything it saves after he reached the menu item limit, not save.

I tried to put this code in php.ini (root folder and wp- admin) , but nothing works .

```
max_input_vars = 3000;
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000
```

phpinfo:

Directive   /     Local Value  /  Master Value

max_input_vars  5000    1000

suhosin.post.max_vars   1000    1000

suhosin.request.max_vars    1000    1000

Comment: Try to check it <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>, that value have changed or not.

Comment: max_input_vars 5000 1000

suhosin.post.max_vars 1000 1000

suhosin.request.max_vars 1000 1000



without changes. What can I do more ?

Answer (score 0):

**1) Editing the .htaccess file.**
The first method you could try is to edit the .htaccess file which is stored in the home directory of your WordPress installation. You’ll have to connect to your FTP account using some FTP client like FileZilla. Once you connected, open .htaccess file and add the following code snippet:

php_value max_input_vars 5000

From here you can increase the max_input_vars limit from 1000 to 5000, which will allow your menu items limit in WordPress to increase automatically. You can also try to increase the value from 5000 to 7000 or more if the limitations persist, however – another reason they may persist is because the PHP server is not responding to your code entry, and in that case you could try to use the solution number two.

**2)  Editing PHP.INI file.**

Editing the Php.ini file is the same thing as with the .htaccess. You need to locate your PHP.ini file on your server via FTP and add the following lines of code:

suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000

or this:

max_input_vars = 5000

**Note : restart the server if necessary. if you are working with php.ini**